# CRM view in a iframe now opens in a new window, why?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm

It has worked for over a year and started opening in a new window.  I am not aware of anything changing.
I made it following the guide at [Stunnware](http://www.stunnware.com/crm2/topic.aspx?id=AdvancedFind1).

The code in the page is:

```
<html>
<head/>
<body class='stage' onload='resultRender.submit()'>
    <FORM id='resultRender' method='post' action='/ALI/AdvancedFind/fetchData.aspx' target='resultFrame'>
    <INPUT value='<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false"><entity name="account"><attribute name="websiteurl"/><attribute name="accountnumber"/><attribute name="new_geocat"/><attribute name="new_contracttype"/><attribute name="name"/><attribute name="accountid"/><order attribute="name" descending="false"/><filter type="and"><condition attribute="parentaccountid" operator="null"/><condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0"/></filter></entity></fetch>' type=hidden name=FetchXml> 
    <INPUT value='<grid name="resultset" object="1" jump="name" select="1" preview="1" icon="1"><row name="result" id="accountid"><cell name="name" width="200"/><cell name="new_contracttype" width="125"/><cell name="new_geocat" width="100"/><cell name="accountnumber" width="100"/><cell name="websiteurl" width="100"/></row></grid>' type='hidden' name='LayoutXml'> 
    <INPUT value='account' type='hidden' name='EntityName'> 
    <INPUT value='{00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000000666000}' type='hidden' name='DefaultAdvFindViewId'> 
    <INPUT value='{B444C27F-FC37-DD11-BDAA-000C292407C5}' type='hidden' name='ViewId'> 
    <INPUT value='1039' type='hidden' name='ViewType'> 
    <INPUT value='name' type='hidden' name='SortCol'> 
    <INPUT value='false' type='hidden' name='SortDescend'> 
    </FORM>
</body>
```

Comment: got a URL? this is hard to debug without

Comment: a url would be helpful. does the resultFrame still exist. If can't find that it may be opening in a new window instead.

Comment: My entry in SiteMap.xml is "<SubArea Id="nav_parents" Url="http://awcrm01/_root/parents.htm" Title="Parent Accounts" />"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out after trial and error.  I added the line below to my HTML page, right after the form.

```
<iframe id='resultFrame' ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You also may try:

From the Iframe properties window, make sure that the "restrict cross frame scripting" check box is de-selected.

This solved a problem of mine that was similar to the one above.

thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Well the web page was opening in the new window because forms target property is set to resultframe, but specified frame it is not there on the page. So as a default action page is getting opened in the new window.
Just remove the frame's target property and you are done. Now frame will open in the same window.
You can specify target as '_self" as well.